# Snap two point layers PostGIS based on a field

Tags: qgis, postgis, vector, snapping

I'd like to know if it's possible to snap point to point automatically in QGIS, only when the two layers have the same attribute value in a field. For example, in the first pic they are far away and they have different attribute values; in the second pic I set the same values, so I need to snap/move these automatically. They are PostGIS layers. [image]

[image]

Any suggestions?